# Bitcoind list all transactions from all accounts with listtransactions cli command

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, daemon

If you run `bitcoin-cli listtransactions "" 9999999` you receive a list of transactions from your default bitcoind account. I would like to receive the transactions of **all** accounts on my daemon, including the default account.

Comment: Does `bitcoin-cli listtransactions "*" 9999999` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. I was having issues with that line because I didn't realise the * requires quotes. Please post and I will accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to receive the transactions of all accounts on my daemon,
>   including the default account.

`$ bitcoin-cli listtransactions "*" 9999999`